# Dynamic transparent images using AlphaImageLoader in IE6

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-6, png, transparent

The following code works fine when I have an image in IE6 that i want to make transparent.

`<img src="image.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; filter:
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='image.png', sizingMethod='scale')" />`

However the following does not. In this example I am using a dynamically generated PNG file.

I assume its because the filter doesn't know that the image is actually a PNG

`<img src="/dynimg/createImg.aspx?id=123" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; filter:
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='dynimg/createImg.aspx?id=123', sizingMethod='scale')" />`

Is there any other way to apply the 'filter' and force it to assume that my image is actaully a PNG.

Note: The image.png file in the non-dynamic situation was actually generated by my dynamic aspx page - so theres nothing wrong with the dynamically image created.

Comment: Are the HTTP headers for the dyn png image set correctly?

Comment: It sounds like you are assuming that the filter is using the filename extension to determine that the file is a png?  If that is what the filter is truly doing you could be out of luck.  Try changing the extension of the png file in your first example and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out when you use an IMG control the IMG.src image is displayed on top of the filtered image (which is the transparent one).

i made an assumption that the above works, when in fact it doesnt. i tricked myself into thinking it worked because of the sequence of things i'd done.

It actually doesnt matter if its dynamic or not.